# Записать в файл все числа

Tags: java, файлы, запись

Нужно из файла записать в другой файл **все** числа, например:

Файл: 12 text var2 14 8v 1

Результат записи: 12 14 1

Пример кода:

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Pattern p;
Matcher m;

String fileName1 = bf.readLine();
String fileName2 = bf.readLine();
char[] chars = new char[0];
String s;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName1));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName2));

while (reader.ready()) {
    chars = new char[reader.read()];
}
```

Знаю, что можно реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений, но пока не знаю как.

Comment: а проблема где?

Comment: в том, чтобы записать только числа во второй файл, используя regex

Comment: необходимо четко сформулировать вопрос и проблему. чтобы можно было дать на него ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("output.txt"))) {
    Files
         //читаем построчно файл
         .lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
         //разбиваем строки на лексемы
         .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")))
         //оставляем только те, что являются числами
         .filter(s -> s.matches("^[\\d]+$"))
         //записываем в файл
         .forEach(s -> {
                     try {
                        writer.write(s);
                        writer.write(" ");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
         });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Читаете строку и отправляете ее в `StringTokenizer` в качестве разделителя, используя символ пробела.
2. Для каждого токена делаете `Integer.parseInt(token)`.
3. Если не будет исключения - значит это число, пишем его в выходной файл + пробел. Иначе - пропускаем и берем следующий токен.

Comment: чтобы не было лишнего пробела, лучше добавлять его **перед** числом, кроме самого первого.